# Is there a way to programmatically close the connection pool with MySQL in my tests?

Tags: mysql, kotlin, testing, ktor

I'm trying to create an integration test for my Ktor backend application by following `Testing` guide in the Ktor Documentation here: https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html#environment, where the target server connects a real database (MySQL + Hikari + Exposed) using Docker.
I could set the test server and run the integration tests successfully though, the problem I have now is even when the test case with `testApplication` block has finished, it looks the connection pool still exist until all test cases finish and this results in the situation where the HikariPools are created for each test case and it occurs `Too Many Connection` Error.

For example, when I set `maximumPoolSize = 4` and run 20 integration test case, then 4 * 20 = 80 connections are created as far as I see the mySQL stats.

Is there any way to reuse the connection pool between tests or delete connections programmatically?

My integration are structured like followings:

integration test code

```
class ExampleIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    fun `Integration Test for the Example endpoints`() = testApplication {
        environment {
           config = ApplicationConfig(application_integration_test.conf)
        }
        val response = client.post("/path/example/test") {
             header("Authorization", dummyToken)
             header(contentType, APPLICATION_JSON)
             body?.let { setBody(body) }
        }
        assertEquals(201, response.status)
        assertEquals("[]", response.bodyAsText())
        ...
```

and the data source configs in `application_integration_test.conf` are like followings:

```
   database {
        driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test?useSSL=false"
        username = testuser
        password = password
        maximumPoolSize = 4
        isAutoCommit = false
        transactionIsolation = TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
        connectionTimeout = 60000
        maxLifetime = 20000000
        idleTimeout = 10000000
        leakDetectionThreshold = 8000
    }
```

I run the mySQL with docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-for-unit-tests:
    image: test/mysql-test
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      # setting parent directory as context to read files in other directory
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/mysqltest/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: testuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    # comment in bellow to change user group and avoid error in windows docker-tools
    # command: bash -c 'usermod -o -u 1000 mysql; groupmod -o -g 500 mysql; chown -R mysql:root /var/run/mysqld/; /entrypoint.sh mysqld --user=mysql --console'
    volumes:
      - ./mysqltest/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7-debian

# copy conf file
COPY ./docker/mysqltest/mysql.conf.d/test-api.cnf /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/test-api.cnf

# Set debian default locale to ja_JP.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    echo "ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen ja_JP.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ja_JP.UTF-8
```

I want my integration tests to run in the GitHub Actions finally, so I don't want restart mySQL for each tests.

Comment: If your tests are run in parallel how would you reuse connections? You can connect to the database once and use that connection for each test.

Comment: > You can connect to the database once and use that connection for each test.

Thank you, yeah that should work but I have no idea how I can configure to make each test reuse the connection.. Could you kindly elaborate a bit about how to do that?

Comment: I think you can use a top-level lazy property to establish a connection to the database once and to expose a single instance of the database connection.